# How to fade out a mesh?

Tags: animation

I have a very very simple animation where I have to fade out a mesh, from a complete opacity to zero. How do I achieve this?

Comment: Are you using BI or cycles?

Comment: I would like to keep the Blender standard renderer, is it too difficult if not with Cycles?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the materials tab of your mesh, add a new material if there is not one already. Then, scroll down until you find the transparency tab. Enable transparency, and you will see a slider that allows you to change the opacity (or transparency) of the material, and thus, the mesh. I would use z-transparency as it is the most realistic.

With the opacity set to full, choose the frame when you want to begin the fade, put your mouse over the opacity slider <kbd>I</kbd>. Then, move to the frame when you want the mesh to be transparent, slide the opacity slider to 0 and hit <kbd>I</kbd> (with your mouse over the slider) again.

This technique is for blender internal

Comment: THank You, just done - but if I play the preview, will I see it fading out? Do I have to render the animation to see the effect?

Comment: I tried as you said some 2-3 times but I cannot see it from the animation player

Comment: By animation player, do you mean the viewport? If you use rendered shading in the viewport (it's in the same drop down as solid and wireframe in the latest version of blender), and then advance frame by frame through the animation, I believe you can see the change in the viewport. However, you could also just render one frame in the middle of the transition to make sure it's working

Comment: If you enable *Transparency* in *Properties > Object > Display* with the object in question selected, it will be visible in solid view as well.

Comment: @Matthew Fennell
What About with the Scroll Bar? (i dont know the real term. The one that shows keyframes)

Comment: It doesn't look like my material is doing anything. With the full understanding that this question is 5 years old, is there anything else I can try?

Answer (score 0):

Using threejs. set the property transparent of a mesh's material to be true. Then change the opacity of that mesh using KeyframeTrack. See the code below

```
const liftTrack3 = new THREE.BooleanKeyframeTrack(
'innerblock.material.transparent',
[5, 6],
[false, true]
```

);

```
const liftTrack4 = new THREE.NumberKeyframeTrack(
'innerblock.material.opacity',
[6, 8],
[1, 0]
```

);

```
 const duration = 10;
const clip = new THREE.AnimationClip('lift', duration, [liftTrack3, liftTrack4]);
const mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer(scene);
 const AnimationAction = mixer.clipAction(clip);
AnimationAction.play();
```